# Presenter view in window mode while slideshow is in fullscreen?

Tags: macos, microsoft-powerpoint

Is there any way to use the **presenter view in a window mode** while the slideshow is on a second monitor in fullscreen?

I tried all the slideshow options. Either both can be in fullscreen or only the slideshow in window mode which won't provide a presenter view.

I want to use my main monitor to not only show the presenter view but utilise other apps on it as well while keeping a slideshow in fullscreen on the second monitor which is shared online via zoom/ms teams on which I also switch to other apps i.e. demo in a browser.

Also when switching between presenter view and another running app then the slideshow on another monitor goes away and reveals other apps on that monitor i.e. open browser, which is very bad experience as it makes it much harder to control.

I'm shocked there is no way to do this, unless I'm missing something or there is any workaround for mac? This is no problem in windows as it has the icons unmaximize and maximize or minimize icons.

Comment: Are you running your screens in separate Spaces or as a pair? I don't have direct experience with Presenter, but this can affect many apps if you want to split them between displays.

Comment: yes as separate displays since mirroring won't enable me to have different apps on different screens. ;) it looks like Microsoft did not implement the equivalent for OSX or preferred to use the true fullscreen mode instead of maximized window mode on PC with window options to change it. Presenter View is a feature of PPT, it runs on a separate monitor compared to the slideshow.

Comment: I didn't mention mirroring - of course that wouldn't work. System prefs > Mission Control > 'Displays have separate Spaces'  test with it on & off. [I can't swap to test because it breaks my workflow]

Comment: Ah sorry misunderstood you and wasn't aware of "spaces' as such. I tried it out but made no difference. The main issue is that the app goes into a native full-screen mode, it doesn't even provide the full-screen button that normally apps have when pressed. The separate spaces is currently enabled and I understood are more about using grid layouts, split view and maybe virtual desktops.

Comment: I had this problem too, because I needed to be able to access other windows to drag them to the monitor with the slideshow during the slideshow, but powerpoint didn't let me view presenter view in a window, so I was forced to go back to powerpoint slideshow on a single monitor only, and couldn't access my notes pages (normally in presenter view) during the whole presentation :-(

Comment: Is the solution to have 3 monitors, since powerpoint will need full screen on both monitors?

Comment: Indeed, how crazy right? I don't understand how managers in Dev and marketing can miss this or make a decision to favour one situation as in true full screen by default and sacrifice the other existing option compared to windows to provide an un-maximize / window mode. It's unacceptable as this is a major downside especially for corporate use.

Comment: Most other other apps provide both options. I wouldn't be surprised if this will either take ages for them to implement or never based on the feedback I've seen and the lack of updates to Mac Office apps, seems they don't care as much. Unfortunately the only work around is to use CMD + TAB to keep cycling back and forth between apps just to be able to use presenter view and other apps on one monitor while having slideshow presented on a second monitor. Oh and while viewing presenter screen you can't reach the dock to switch or open other apps.... Horrible.

Comment: Yes, crazy. I have too many applications running at the same time, so CMD + TAB is not a practical workaround, but thanks for pointing that out. Maybe I need to print out my notes pages on paper for my next presentation. Ugh!

Comment: We need to get more Mac users to submit feedback and company via the PPT app help menu!

Comment: LOL PowerPoint does not even provide MAXIMIZE window for regular use like most other apps do, how lame, one has to manually adjust/re-size the window or has to use the true full screen (which isn't always desirable).

Answer (score 0):

I want the same arrangement. And while it’s not yet technically possible as far as I can tell, this is the closest I could get:

How to screenshare PowerPoint on Zoom with only one or two monitors and not lose view of participants on Mac:

- In PP ribbon, click “Slide Show”, “Presenter View”.
- In Z, click “Share Screen”, “Microsoft PowerPoint - Slide Show” (not “Presenter”, not “Desktop”), “Share”.
- Your Zoom meeting will collapse into a floating row of buttons and a floating grid of participants.
- Drag those anywhere, even on top of the show view. Participants see only your show view (even if you don’t see your show view).
- Participants see your mouse pointer if it hovers the presenter view’s show preview or if it hovers the separate show view.
- If you enlarge your mouse pointer in macOS System Prefs for greater visibility, participants only see it as large when you hover the show view.

Bonus info:

- Press command-P to change your mouse pointer to a pen that can draw on your slides.
- Command-A restores the automatic pointer.
- Control-click can change pen color, but not pen size.
- When you exit your slideshow, PowerPoint will ask if you want to save your scribblings.

Versions:

- macOS 12.4 “Monterey”
- PowerPoint 16.62 “2019”
- Zoom 5.10.4

Answer (score 0):

Technically this is not possible.

But there is a feature request open at Microsoft.

If you want this feature, [please go upvote and comment on this ticket](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/a3028831-dd1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8945). Activity there is the only thing that will get this implemented!